# Why does using BinaryWrite make my file bigger?

Tags: files-and-directories, streams

I have a binary file [00010005.dat](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xiaozh/SE/00010005.dat). I want to normalize the matrix so I use the following code:

```
normalize[file_] := 
   Module[{matfile = OpenRead[file, BinaryFormat -> True], data, Mat}, 
     SetStreamPosition[matfile, 0];
     data =  Partition[BinaryReadList[matfile, "Real32", ByteOrdering -> 1], 1297];
     Close[matfile]; 
     Mat = 
       Join[
         data[[All, ;; 45]], 
         Transpose[Standardize /@ Transpose[data[[All, 46 ;; 47]]]], 
         data[[All, 48 ;;]], 
         2]; 
     BinaryWrite[file, Flatten @ Mat, "Real32", ByteOrdering -> 1];];
```

the size of the file is:

```
FileByteCount["00010005.dat"]/2^10.
(* 891.688 *)
```

Then I normalize the file:

```
Do[normalize["00010005.dat"];, 5]
```

But this will change the size of the file.

```
 FileByteCount["00010005.dat"]/2^10.
 (* 14267. *)
```

Very strange.  And using `Streams` I get:

[image]

But in `normalize` I already close the file actually. (Maybe I use the `Close` wrongly?)

So what's my problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Why do you run the `normalize` code five times?

Comment: You close the stream after reading but not after writing.

Comment: Its good practice to do a explicit `OpenWrite`, that way you will get a nice error message if the file is already open because you forgot to close it.

Comment: @SimonWoods you are right ,Thank you!